# Is it possible to remain previous values from a List in C#

Tags: c#, list

Here is my sample code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var i in numbers())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(i);
        }
    }

    private List<int> numbers()
    {
        List<int> counts = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            counts.Add(i);
        }
        return counts;
    }
```

I want to know if it is possible to not overwrite and remain the previous values from a `List<>`. In my sample if I click the button it will populate 1,2,3,4,5 in the listbox and when I click the button again I am expecting an output of 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5 this values is what I am expecting from my `List<>` How could I possibly do that? BTW, the listbox there is just for display purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `List<int> counts = new List<int>();`, you create a new, empty list. This happens anew with each call to `numbers()`.

If I understand your question correctly, you want `numbers()` to add the five numbers to an existing lists, that hence grows with each call to `numbers()`.

In order to achieve this, do not create a new `List<int>` with each call of `numbers()` that you return as a result value; instead create a private field for that list and modify it with each call to `numbers()`:

```
private List<int> counts = new List<int>();

private List<int> numbers()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        counts.Add(i);
    }
    return counts;
}
```

Note that `numbers()` will still return the list, but it's not a new list; it's the same list instance every time.

Comment: @GrayFullBuster: I have just added some example code that shows how to declare `counts` outside of your `numbers()` method.

Comment: @GrayFullBuster: Ok; please mark the answer as accepted if your question was solved, or otherwise feel free to ask here in the comments section if something is unclear to you :-)

Answer (score 3):

You just have to remove the `listBox1.Items.Clear();` therefore.

Apart from that, you can use `Enumerable.Concat` to append items:

```
var num1 = numbers();
var num2 = numbers();
foreach(var num in num1.Concat(num2))
{
    //  ...
}
```

or maybe using `Enumerable.Range` from the start, assuming you always want to add  the same 5 items:

```
int currentCount = listBox1.Items.Count;
int groupSize = 5;
var allItems = Enumerable.Range(0, currentCount + groupSize)
                         .Select(i => 1 + i % groupSize);
foreach(var item in allItems)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, but what would be my List contains?

Comment: Is this applicable if I click items more than twice or etc.?

Comment: @GrayFullBuster: Added another approach to always add the same group of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`Clear` removes all items in the list. If you simple want to append all items from new list to the old list use [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az.aspx):

```
 listBox1.Items.AddRange(numbers());
```

Comment: Yes, but if i remove theclear thing, what would be my List contains?

Answer (score 1):

Declare counts outside of the numbers() method, at class level. Every call to this method will then add 1,2,3,4,5 into the list.

```
private List<int> _counts = new List<int>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var i in numbers())
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(i);
    }
}

private List<int> numbers()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        _counts.Add(i);
    }
    return counts;
}
```